# how to send a selected database value that is inside loop to another page in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have made a form in php and inside form there is a loop that extracts multiple values from database(img,name,availability,..) for multiple books i have made a table to display those values to user and after displaying these data in table i have made an issue button inside loop so that every book has its issue button.

***My problem is that i have to only retrieve id of that book for which user click issue button. i tried storing it in cookie but it send the id of the first book displayed then i tried get method but that results in sending the last book that is displayed on screen id. but i want is that it should send the id of book which is selected by user***

display books

```
    echo "<form action='issue.php' method='get'>";
                while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                    echo "<div id='img_div' style='background-color:#fff;'> ";
                    echo "<img src='books/".$row['image']."'>";
                    // echo "</div>";<div id='text'>
                    $isbn=$row['isbn'];

                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='isb' value='$isbn' />";
                    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<table>";


                    echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NAME</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['name']."</td></tr>";
                    echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AVAILABILITY</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['availabilty']."</td></tr>";
                    echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CATEGORY</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['category']."</td></tr>";
                    echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>

                    <button type='submit' name='issue'>issue</button></td></tr>";
                    echo "</table>";
                    echo "</div><br/>";
                    if (isset($_GET['issue'])) {
                        # code...
                        $bookid=$isbn;
                    setcookie("bid",$bookid);
                        if(!isset($_COOKIE['bid'])){
                            echo "COOKIE NOT SET";
                        }
                        else{ 
                            echo "COOKIE SET SUCCESSFULLY";
                        }
                    }
```

issue.php(in which i want to send id)

```
    if(isset($_GET['issue'])){
                $bookid=$_GET['isb'];

    $dbser="localhost";
                $use="[redacted]";  
                $pasw="[redacted]";
                $db="[redacted]";
                $con=mysqli_connect($dbser,$use,$pasw,$db);
                mysqli_select_db($con,$db)or die("db not connected");
                    $userid=$_COOKIE['id'];
                    $id=$_SESSION['user']['username'];
                    $query = "select id from user_account where username='$id'";
                    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
                    $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                        $uid=$row['id'];



                    echo "$uid";
                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo "$bookid";
                            $query = "INSERT INTO issue (bookid, userid)
                 VALUES ('$bookid', '$uid')";
             mysqli_query($con, $query)or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: [setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output, including <html> and <head> tags as well as any whitespace.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a way to select a single row then submit that with the form. That can be accomplished by adding a Radio button to your table inside the form. The user will check the radio button for the item they want then click the submit button.

Here is an example of what that code could look like for your page.

**display books**

```
<form action='issue.php' method='get'>
while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $isbn=$row['isbn'];

    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<table>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"optradio\" value=\"".$isbn."\"></td>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NAME</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AVAILABILITY</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['availabilty']."</td>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CATEGORY</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['category']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "</table>";
}

echo "<button type='submit' name='issue'>issue</button>";
echo "</form>";
```

Here is a HTML snippet so you can see what that PHP code would output in HTML. Click "Run snippet code" below to see the preview.

```html
<form action='issue.php' method='get'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="1"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NAME</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;name1</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AVAILABILITY</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;availability1</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CATEGORY</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;category1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="2"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NAME</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;name2</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AVAILABILITY</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;availability2</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CATEGORY</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;category2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<button type='submit' name='issue'>issue</button>
</form>
```

Then in **issue.php** you would look for `$_GET['optradio']` to get the selected value.

```
if(isset($_GET['issue'])){
            $bookid=$_GET['optradio'];

$dbser="localhost";
...
...
...
```